# Difference between nautilus and sudo nautilus

Tags: sudo, nautilus, file-manager

I would like to know the difference between `nautilus` and `sudo nautilus`. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You should never use sudo nautilus.  You are mixing command line elevation of privileges with a gui program.  May cause errors and things changed get written into /'s home not the user /home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default when you start an application via sudo it will run with superuser privileges which means you can do do anything with your filesystem and data (including destroying everything quite easily) - this is **not** recommended unless you fully understand why you need this or that command to run under `root`.

TLDR: In short, never run `nautilus` via `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help